# "Let them never be born" or "Let them never to be born?"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, let

Which one is more grammatical? Example:

> Deformed animals suffer a lot. Why not let them never (to) be born?

Comment: BTW, a controversial statement. Maybe they are happy as they are and take life as it comes.

Comment: I would advise you to change your example sentence.

Comment: FYI, this is a highly offensive notion to most parents with disabled children, to most Christians, or to any who oppose [eugenics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugenics), which, since WWII, is just about every civilized country

Comment: Yeah, apologies I couldn't think of another example. How about now?

Comment: Sounds like a "topic sentence" for a persuasive essay in an English class. The original and the edit sound bog-standard for such an assignment. If it offends, avoid English classes... and Jonathan Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After "let," we never use an infinitive with "to" but always a bare infinitive. Therefore, the option without "to" is better.

That being said, the sentence doesn't make a lot of sense, because there are two negatives in it, which is hard to parse. I think what you mean is something like

> Why even allow them to be born?

or

> Why even let them be born?

Comment: Your version seems to suggest that maybe we should deprive them of the right to live, whereas the original question seems to suggest that maybe we should give them the right to skip a life of suffering. The difference is huge.

Comment: @JiK, there may be a difference in theory, but in practice it appears that the goal is to cause the animals to be stillborn; and since we are talking about animals, it's clear that they would not be the ones doing the choosing. So, pretending that we are giving them input in the choice is misleading or disingenuous.

Comment: "Pretending that we are giving them input in the choice" may be the goal of the original question. This is a question about English, not about ethics or logical thinking in ethics.

Answer (score 0):

*Why not let them never be born* is the correct syntax.

We use the bare infinitive *be* in certain constructions.

I demand that you *be* there at 3 o'clock.

*Be* there by 5 if you want a free toy.

The train may/must/can/will/should/ought to *be* early.

My first two examples are closest to yours,  as they are commands.

The Beatles song "Let it be" follows the same syntax as what you ask about.